# How to limit class instantiation by scope in type di

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, typedi

## Introduction

I got an express server

```
export const Search = {
start: () => {
    useContainer(Container);

    const app = express();

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        req.setTimeout(0); // no timeout for all requests, your server will be DoS'd
        next();
    });

    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    // Configure controllers
    useExpressServer(app, {
        routePrefix: '/api',
        controllers: [
            SearchController,
        ],
    });

    app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.path.startsWith('/api')) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.end();
        }
    });

    const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        Logger.info(`⚡️[server]: Server is running at https://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
    });

    server.setTimeout(0);
},
```

};

`SearchController` in turn uses type di to instantiate a Service class in it's constructor like so

```
@JsonController('/search')
@Service()
export class SearchController {

  constructor(
    private graph: SearchService,
  ) {
    ...
}
```

and when we get a post search request, we process it inside the search service like so:

@Post('')
async search(@Body() query:searchQuery, @Res() response: any) {
query = toLowerCase(query);
const results = await this.graph.search(query);
return response.send(results);
}

## Problem

Inside the search service, the search method does this

```
async search(query: searchQuery) {
    this.queryPersonId = query.personId;
```

the problem here is that this.queryPersonId shares this parameter from across different requests! So what's happening here is that we're not instantiating a separate Search Service *per* request! How do we do that with type di?

Comment: Scoped or not, having a query depend on some shared parameter in a service is a terrible pattern that what you're asking for won't necessarily solve.  Given typeid's documentation page on using a "scoped container" is a blank page, I'd say you may want to find a more mature solution.